# Why does vim-plug set formatoptions for xml files?

Tags: vim

I installed [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) in `.vim/autoload/`

When I open any XML file and check the `:verbose set fo?` format options it says:

> formatoptions=tcq
>
> ```
>    Last set from /usr/share/vim/vimrc
> ```

After enabling vim-plug in `~/.vimrc` (without plugins):

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
call plug#end()
```

I get this output:

> formatoptions=croql
>
> ```
>    Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/xml.vim
> ```

Why are the formatoptions different from before?

---

`/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/xml.vim` contains the code below:

```
setlocal formatoptions-=t
if !exists("g:ft_xml_autocomment") || (g:ft_xml_autocomment == 1)
    setlocal formatoptions+=croql
endif
```

But `g:ft_xml_autocomment` is undefined in both cases!

Comment: Are you doing `call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')` *after* your `set formatoptions` in `.vimrc`? It's generally a good idea to load all your plugins at the top and then set options afterwards. I'm not sure what the root cause is, but that may solve the problem.

Comment: @JimStewart I don't set the `formatoptions` at all - it's from the default `vimrc`.

Comment: Do you have `filetype plugin indent on` or `filetype plugin on` somewhere in your `vimrc`?

Comment: Well scratch that, [it looks](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/master/plug.vim#L275) like vim-plug arbitrarily enables filetype detection. This means that you get filetype-specific settings instead of the defaults. It's usually a good thing and having `filetype plugin indent on` in your `vimrc` is generally recommended but the author shouldn't do what he does.

Comment: @romainl you are right! After removing that line from `plug.vim` I get `formatoptions=tcq` - I still don't understand why though as `g:ft_xml_autocomment` is not set.

Comment: @romainl apparently `filetype plugin indent on` is by design https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/issues/379

Comment: It's bad design. He should save the user's settings and revert them when he is done.